# Flush current DNS server in resolvectl?

Tags: linux, fedora

So everytime I disconnect from VPN, I have VPN's DNS server entry in my
`resolvectl` is there anyway I can flush it?

EDIT: Tried resolvectl flushcache

I want to reset Global DNS value in resolvectl

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo resolvectl flush-caches
```

should do the trick

Remember that you can often check a short(er) form list of command options by reading the output of your command after passing -h as the option.

Comment: I tried this, but I want to flush Global DNS in resolvectl.

Comment: What OS are you using ? Your network manager system ?

Comment: OS : Fedora::Latest